# How to draw random images with python and predict on it with CNN/ANN/neural networks?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

Can anyone tell me what libraries are needed to draw the attached drawing?

Comment: that's seems a little rough, why are you trying to do that? what's the application of theese. I don't think that doing this is a great idea

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You will find it easier to get help if your question is specific and has a minimal version of the code you are trying to get working

Comment: Hello guys. As mentioned, I am very new to python and machine learning and I have a very limited knowledge in different libraries of python. The application is a project that I have and for my project it is necessary to solve it. If you guys can let me know the needed libraries to work with, I can try and find the way. It is definitely not an easy task nor is it the type of usual questions you get in stackoverflow. I appreciate any comment that helps to solve it.

Comment: Anyone here can name the libraries to use for this project? e.g. what library shall I use to create the circles, and what library to draw the contour.